# Data table not show print

Tags: php, laravel-5, datatable, datatables

when i write "

```
print

 "$(function () {
        $("#example1").DataTable(
            {
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'print',
                        text: 'Print current page',
                        autoPrint: false
                    }]
            }
        );
        $("#structure_field-add-form").validate({});
    });"
```

this not make print button show to use it how can I fix this, please? output like the picture

[image]

Comment: You're going in and out of double quotes, breaking the string. I'm surprised you're not getting a syntax error.

Comment: no no in real code I don't have double quotes 
 $(function () {
        $("#example1").DataTable(
            {
                dom: "Bfrti",
                buttons: [ "print"]
            }
        );
        $("#structure_field-add-form").validate({});
    });

Answer (score 0):

Did you put all required JS files in place ?

please check this link. https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html

You have to add following JS files.

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js
//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js
```

Also please check below code. this is the working example of datatable button which I am using in my project.

```
var table1 =  $('#task-table').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'csv','excel','selectAll','selectNone',
            {
                extend: 'copy',
                text: 'COPY ALL',
                className: 'pull_right',
                exportOptions: {
                    modifier: {
                        page: 'all'
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0,
            checkboxes: {
                'selectRow': true
            }
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'multi',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        "iDisplayLength" : 20,
    });
```